# Custom validation error no longer working in Alamofire 5

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, alamofire5

Using Alamofire 4, we had an API response validator in place we invoked like so:

```
func request<Endpoint: APIEndpoint>(_ baseURL: URL, endpoint: Endpoint, completion: @escaping (_ object: Endpoint.ResponseType?, _ error: AFError?) -> Void) -> DataRequest where Endpoint.ResponseType: Codable {
    let responseSerializer = APIObjectResponseSerializer(endpoint)
    let request = self.request(baseURL, endpoint: endpoint)
        .validate(APIResponseValidator.validate)                << VALIDATOR PASSED HERE
        .response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer) { response in
            completion(response.value, response.error)
    }
    return request
}
```

It looks like this:

```
static func validate(request: URLRequest?, response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data?) -> Request.ValidationResult {
    // **INSERT OTHER FAILURE CHECKS HERE**

    // Verify server time is within a valid time window.
    let headers = response.allHeaderFields
    guard let serverTimeString = headers["Date"] as? String, let serverTime = DateUtils.headerDateFormatter().date(from: serverTimeString) else {
        Log.error("APIValidation: no Date in response header")
        return .failure(APIError.appTimeSettingInvalid))
    }

    // **INSERT OTHER FAILURE CHECKS HERE**

    return .success(Void())
}
```

The appropriate error would make it back to the request completion handler,

```
▿ APIError
  ▿ appTimeSettingInvalid
```

and we could update the UI with the right error, everyone was happy.

But now with Alamofire, it's this:

```
▿ Optional<Error>
 ▿ some : AFError
  ▿ requestRetryFailed : 2 elements
   ▿ retryError : AFError
    ▿ responseValidationFailed : 1 element
     ▿ reason : ResponseValidationFailureReason
      ▿ customValidationFailed : 1 element
       ▿ error : APIError
        ▿ appTimeSettingInvalid      << Original custom error
   ▿ originalError : AFError
    ▿ responseValidationFailed : 1 element
      ▿ reason : ResponseValidationFailureReason
       ▿ customValidationFailed : 1 element
        ▿ error : APIError
         ▿ appTimeSettingInvalid      << Original custom error
```

Which I need to access like this:

```
if let underlyingError = (error as? AFError)?.underlyingError as? AFError,
    case let AFError.requestRetryFailed(_, originalError) = underlyingError,
    case let AFError.responseValidationFailed(reason) = originalError,
    case let .customValidationFailed(initialCustomError) = reason {
    showAlert(initialCustomError)
}
```

This seems absurd. What am I missing? Why did the custom validation fail when nothing has changed about the method, and why is it wrapped in a layer of other errors? Why retry a request when the validation is going to fail the same way?

**How do I get my custom error back, consistently, across all my requests?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Alamofire 5, all errors are returned contained in an `AFError` instance, including custom validation errors. This allows our `Response` types to contain typed errors and provides a consistent error type. However, the validation API still returns `Error` instances, unfortunately, so there is an additional layer to peel back. You can use the convenience `asAFError` property to perform the cast and the `underlyingError` property to grab any underlying errors. Use of `switch` statements can also make the extraction easier. You can also `mapError` on responses to extract the specific error types you want.

As for retry, it's likely your retrier hasn't been updated to extract the errors in such a way that retry is properly avoided with your custom error type.

Comment: Sure, we'll be taking a look at it for Alamofire 6.

Answer (score 0):

Code sample to convert the AFError to normal custom Error:

As usual use the switch on the result type, then on error:

```
{ (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(_, _, _):
   ,.............
     case .failure(let error):
     let afError = error.asAFError?.underlyingError ?? error 
     completion(afError)
```

asAFError?.underlyingError is available in Alomafire framework.